# Unbind solution from source control

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, source-control-bindings

In my VS Professional 2013,I copied and pasted a solution from the source control workspace to my desktop but everytime I open the solution I get these messages:

```
The mappings for the solution could not be found.
The mappings for the solution could not be found.
The mappings for the solution could not be found.
The mappings for the solution could not be found.
The active solution has been temporarily disconnected from source control because the server is unavailable.  To attempt to reconnect to source control, close and then re-open the solution when the server is available.  If you want to connect this solution to another server, use the Change Source Control dialog.
```

How can I completely remove everything related to the TSF from the solution?

I already tried the following suggestions from answers in similar questions:

- select the solution in the solution explorer, then go to the File menu. Under the file menu, you'll see a Source Control menu. Under that you'll see Change Source Control.Select this, and in the dialog box that comes up, choose "unbind."
- Delete *.vssscc, *.vspscc, files . Open the .sln file with notepad and erase `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) ... EndGlobalSection`

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to remove Source Control Bindings from Visual Studio Solutions and Projects from msdn: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2012/08/11/a-tool-to-remove-source-control-bindings-from-visual-studio-solutions-and-projects.aspx

How to use the tool:

•Copy your solution to a new directory (because the tool does modify files)

•Run this command: VSUnbindSourceControl.exe  (ex. d:\yourfolder)